# Python Boto3 error - "expected string or bytes-like object" when deleting an Amazon S3 object

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3

I am facing a problem with the following line of code (the last line in the lambda code block) when I am trying to test the below lambda function written in Python 3.7 boto3 AWS SDK. The lambda function deletes objects in an S3 bucket, iterating through each object in the bucket.

`client.Object(bucket, key).delete()`

When I am saving and running the code, the error I am getting in the aforementioned line, which is also the last line in the lambda function code block below, is as the following. Requesting help.

> "errorMessage": "expected string or bytes-like object",  "errorType": "TypeError"

[Lambda function code block]

```
import boto3
import json
import uuid
import csv

def lambda_handler(event, context):

   recordId = str(uuid.uuid4())
   print (recordId)
   client = boto3.resource(
       's3',
   region_name='us-east-1',
       aws_access_key_id='XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX' ,
       aws_secret_access_key='XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
   )    

   bucket = client.Bucket('my_bucket')

   dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')

   table = dynamodb.Table('my_dynamo')

   for obj in bucket.objects.all():
        key = obj.key
        body = obj.get()['Body'].read()
        data = body.decode("utf-8") 
        data1 = data.split('\n')

        client.Object(bucket, key).delete()
```

Comment: Can you please add the code snippet it'll be better to understand. Apart from that try to do explicit type conversion of the arguments to string which is throwing error.

Comment: I added the code snippet, can you please suggest! Thanks a lot.

Comment: you have to use `client.Object(bucket.name, key).delete()`, [bucket.name](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#bucket) is the identifier

Answer (score 1):

In the above code you are using the bucket Object for deleting.
You need to replace

```
 client.Object(bucket, key).delete()
```

with

```
 client.Object(bucket.name, key).delete()
```

Since the bucket name and key should be string

Answer (score 0):

I have used Client for deletion. Not resource.
This works fine. You can try this.

```py
client_s3 = boto3.client('s3')
res = client_s3.list_objects(Bucket=bucket_name)
for list_key in res['Contents']:
    client_s3.delete_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=list_key['Key'])
```

This is the structure of res['Contents'] if you need to get any other details:

```
'Key': 'string',
'LastModified': datetime(2015, 1, 1),
'ETag': 'string',
'Size': 123,
'StorageClass':'STANDARD'|'REDUCED_REDUNDANCY'|'GLACIER'|'STANDARD_IA'|'ONEZONE_IA'|'INTELLIGENT_TIERING'|'DEEP_ARCHIVE',
'Owner': {
          'DisplayName': 'string',
          'ID': 'string'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import boto3

bucketName = "your bucketname"
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
s3.Object(bucketName, key).delete()
```